# MVC3 header JavaScript code error for jQueryMobile element

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

can anyone solve this please.i m getting two arrays from action for ids and percentage i try all coding but didnt succeed yet output is not correct

javascript code

```
  @section javascript{
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        var percents = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.percentage)); 
        var ids = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.IDs)); 

        var date = new Date(); 
        var day = date.getDay(); 
        var dayper = (day / 30) * 100; 

        $.each(ids, function(index, id) { 
          var percent = parseInt(percents[index], 10); 
          var element = $('#' + id); 
          element.css('width', percent + '%'); 
          var rA = 100 - percent; 
          var color = 'green'; 

          if (rA - dayper > 40) { 
            color = 'red'; 
          } else if (rA - dayper > 20 && rA - dayper < 40) { 
            color = 'yellow'; 
          } 

          element.css('background-color', color); 
        }); 
    }); 
    </script> 


}
```

and jquerymobile code for implmeting class ui-bar divs

.....................
 ............................

```
<div class="ui-bar-e" id="bdgt_@(item.budgetId)" >
 @Model.currency[l]@item.spentAmount/@Model.currency[l]@item.amount 
</div>
```

..........................................
 ...............................

what is error here

**Edit From Comment**

In action:

```
string[] IDs = new string[bEList.Count]; 
int i = 0; 
foreach(var item in bEList) { 
   IDs[i] = "bdgt_" + item.budgetId; 
   i++; 
} 
ViewBag.IDs = IDs;
```

Comment: In my case, The background is changing just fine. Are you sure you are sending correct ids in `viewbag`?

Comment: @Mohayemin this is code in action
string[] IDs = new string[bEList.Count];
            int i = 0;
            foreach(var item in bEList)
            {
                IDs[i] = "bdgt_" + item.budgetId;
                i++;
            }
            ViewBag.IDs = IDs;
where bElist is list containing objects

Comment: Still no help, because we still do not know what Ids you are sending. You can use developers tool of your browser (eg Firebug in Firefox) to check if the id in javascript and the id in the dome elements are the same. Another way is to debug to check if the ViewBag is alright.

Comment: @Mohayemin gives this error in consol googlechrome browzer
Viewport argument value "device.width" for key "width" not recognized. Content ignored.

Comment: I have no idea what that error means, but you can check [this](http://royaltutorials.com/viewport-argument-value-device-width-for-key-width-not-recognized-content-ignored/)

Comment: @Mohayemin brother it was browzer problem when i run that code with microsoft IE9 it gives my require result.thnx for helping me